# zsh completion for make: only complete targets from Makefile

Tags: shell, zsh, make, autocomplete

When I am in a directory with `Makefile`, and I use zsh completion for make:

```
make <TAB>
```

it completes two sets of completions:

1. the targets from the Makefile
2. files in current directory

I only want 1)

How can I disable 2) ?

I have pasted here the `_make` completion file: https://ctxt.io/2/AADge23ZFg

Comment: Just for historical purposes, could you provide permanently your code from https://ctxt.io/2/AADge23ZFg? It seems that code will be deleted automatically in <30 days.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The completions come from `_alternative 'targets:…' 'variables:…' '*:…'`.

The [`_alternative`](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Completion-System.html#index-_005falternative) function lists choices between [tags](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Completion-System.html#index-_005ftags). The order and selection of tags can be [configured](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Completion-System.html#Overview-2) with the [`tag-order` style](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Completion-System.html#index-tag_002dorder_002c-completion-style). The context for the style is `:completion::complete:make::` — you can either work this out from the documentation (including that of [`zstyle`](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Zsh-Modules.html#index-zstyle), or read it in the trace produced by `^X?` ([`_complete_debug`](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Completion-System.html#index-_005fcomplete_005fdebug-_0028_005eX_003f_0029)).

To only complete target and variable names, but not file names, as far as I understand, you can set the tag order like this:

```
zstyle ':completion::complete:make::' tag-order 'targets variables' -
```

However, experimentally, this offers no completions at all and I can't figure out why.

What does work, however, and is probably more useful, is to set the tag order to prioritize targets and variable names. Then `make stuffTab` will only try to complete file names if there are no matching targets or variable names.

```
zstyle ':completion::complete:make::' tag-order 'targets variables'
```

Or, to ignore variables unless no targets match, and to ignore files unless neither targets nor variables match:

```
zstyle ':completion::complete:make::' tag-order targets variables
```

(Oh, and for completeness's sake, you can completely disable all file completion for `make` arguments with `zstyle ':completion::complete:make::' file-patterns ''`. But this even disables completions for things like `make -f`, which unfortunately doesn't have a different context string.)

Comment: This command did it for me: `zstyle ':completion::complete:make::' tag-order targets variables`